# Remove text before email address

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, cygwin

I have hundreds of thousands of mostly jumbled lines which contains emails and other data. Everything which appears before an email address is essentially useless, and can be purged/deleted/removed/sliced - unsure of correct terminology, sorry.

I tend to use Cygwin for these types of things, but have been struggling a lot. This is the email regex I generally tend to use:

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}
```

Input:

```
Dog:email@email.com:cat
Pab:email1@hotmail.com:dog
cat:horse:email@jenga.de:cat
bike:michael:david:xenon@gmail.com:cat
inter@outlook.com:bob
```

Desired output:

```
email@email.com:cat
email1@hotmail:dog
email@jenga.de:cat
xenon@gmail.com:cat
inter@outlook.com:bob
```

Comment: You are supposed to post a *question,* not just input and output. See also [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I keep making mistakes on this website. My purpose is to slice everything which appears before an email on every line. I hope my examples portray what I'm trying to do here. I can answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Please [edit] your question into a proper question, including your best attempt so far. Also it's not clear what you mean by "slice". And how exactly will the input differ from what you demonstrate? Show us those variations instead of alluding to them.

Comment: What are you using to perform the edits? We still need to see actual code.

Comment: Sorry, there isn't any code or anything. I'm looking for a line for Cygwin to be created for me to perform this command. I just simply have the text file containing the data.

Comment: "Cygwin" is not a programming language. Are you looking for a `sed` script? Will there always be a colon immediately before the email address?

Comment: Yeah apologies I'm an idiot and my terminology is disgustingly bad. I tend to use: sed/awk generally for these situations.

And no, there isn't always a colon before the email address - but for 90% of the time, there will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp works fine:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
email@email.com
email1@hotmail.com
email@jenga.de
xenon@gmail.com
inter@outlook.com

$ awk 'match($0,/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}/){print substr($0,RSTART)}' file
email@email.com:cat
email1@hotmail.com:dog
email@jenga.de:cat
xenon@gmail.com:cat
inter@outlook.com:bob
```

Since you're on cygwin you have GNU awk which has "inplace" editing available with:

```
awk -i inplace 'script' file
```

but of course **test first**.

Comment: Thankyou very much Ed :)

Comment: Hey Ed, sorry to bring up a post from months ago. But how would I perform this command oppositely. So instead of removing all text which appears "BEFORE" the email address, I would like to remove all text which appears "AFTER".

Comment: Ask a new, followup question.

Answer (score 0):

To remove everything up to and including a colon just before an email,

```
sed 's/.*:\([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\)/\1/' file
```

Generally `sed` does not allow `{2,6}` without options so maybe you have `sed -E` or `sed -r`, in which case the backslashes before the parentheses should probably be removed.

Comment: Hi appreciate your continuous replies. I tried this command against the input format I provided, and the output file contained the exact same data. I switched to EOL from Windows/Unix and vice-versa but I had the same results.

Comment: It doesn't modify the file, it prints to standard output. If you have `sed -i` that should do in-place editing of the file (writing back the changes) but try without that until you see correct results as the regex may still need tweaking, as already explained in this answer.

Comment: Okay thankyou, appreciated.

Comment: In a POSIX BREs (and so in POSIX sed) you just need to escape the `{` and `}`, e.g. `...\{2,6\}...`